# Angular error "Cannot read property 'firstName' of undefined"

Tags: html, angular, http, elasticsearch, get

Hi i am working on a search service to look for usernames in a elasticsearch database but i got the following error when i want to display the f.e. firstName of the user: Cannot read property 'firstName' of undefined.

I am working with Angular and Elasticsearch

service:

```
export class SearchService {

  getElastic = 'http://34.62.28.281:9200/users/_doc/_search?q=';
  private handleError: HandleError;

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    httpErrorHandler: HttpErrorHandler) {
    this.handleError = httpErrorHandler.createHandleError('TimelineService');
  }
  /** GET elasticsearch result */
  getElasticResult( text: string ): Observable<User> {
    this.http.get<User>(this.getElastic + text).subscribe(res => console.log(res));
    return  this.http.get<User>(this.getElastic + text, {responseType: 'json'});

  }
```

**EDIT:**
The new HTML form:

```
<form [formGroup]="angForm2" *ngIf="user != null" (ngSubmit)="getUser()" class="form-inline my-5 my-lg-0">
  <input id="searchText" name="searchText" class="form-control" type="string" placeholder="Search for user" aria-label="Post"
         formControlName="searchText" required>
  <p>{{user?.firstName}}</p>
<button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

the new component:

```
export class SearchServiceComponent implements OnInit {
  user: User;
  angForm2 = this.fb.group({
    searchText: ['', Validators.required]
  });

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getUser();
    this.getObject();
  }

  constructor(private searchservice: SearchService, private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  getUser() {
    const userName = this.angForm2.value.searchText;
    console.log(this.angForm2.value, userName);
    this.searchservice.getElasticResult(userName).subscribe(user => (this.user = user));
  }
  getObject() {
    return this.user;
  }
}
```

Output of user and this.user:

[image]

User interface:

```
export interface User {
  $oid: string;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  username: string;
  password: string;
  follows: User[];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess getObject() is getting called when you load the form, by the time user is undefined so you are getting that error. why dont you just use user?.firstName since you already have the variable defined ?

```
  <p>{{user?.firstName}}</p>
```

Comment: thanks for ur reply, i did change everthing u guys suggested, there is no error anymore but the <p>{{user?.firstname}}</p> is not showing up :/

Answer (score 0):

1.SearchServiceComponent should implement OnInit class and implement its ngOnInit method
2. Call both the methods inside ngOnInit method sequentially
3. Check if this.user is not equal to null or undefined and handle it using ngIf condition
Answered by Sajitharan

Example for OnInit
TS

```
    @Component({selector: 'my-cmp', template: `...`})
class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getUser();
    this.getObject()
  }
getUser() {
    const userName = this.angForm2.value.searchText;
    console.log(this.angForm2.value, userName);
    this.searchservice.getElasticResult(userName).subscribe(user => (this.user = user.hits.hits[0]._source));
  }
  getObject(){}
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, i did change the component and the html form. I edited my post with the new code. I don't get the error anymore but there is no output either. the <p>{{user?.firstname}} is not showing up

Comment: You haven't called getUser and getObject inside ngOnInit. Please try it and let me know

Comment: i did called them but forgot to post the new code ^^ and yeah same thing, not showing up in the <p>

Comment: Can you please console.log in below line
this.searchservice.getElasticResult(userName).subscribe(user => (this.user = user));
as
this.searchservice.getElasticResult(userName).subscribe(user =>  {
console.log(user);
console.log(this.user);
} )

Comment: okay i did that and the console prints all the user data from the elasticsearch database, but still nothing on the <p>user?.firstName</p>

Comment: i added a screenshot of the console in my post

Comment: Please check updated answer for the modification of service

Comment: thanks for the reply but it marks the first "hit" as an error "Property 'hits' does not exist on type 'User'"

Comment: i added the "User" interface in my post

Comment: Both are "hits" and there is no property with the name "hit". Can you please check the implementation once.

Comment: sry i meant hits, i copied ur code directly so there should be no implementation errors

Comment: I am not able to reproduce it on my machine. Would you be able to create the issue on stackblitz ?

Comment: i can offer u the github link : https://github.com/mastalier1997/PRDKE

Comment: I am on it. please give me some time.

Comment: I am not getting any result for searching empty or "e". Can you please check the results once or fill some data. please let me know once you enter some data in the database

Comment: ah sorry yeah, there are some users already in the database. You would only get a response if u write the username in. Examples: "trump" or "elon" (just for 4 names haha)

Comment: Please add me to github collaborator. my username is prasadmahadik. There are lot of changes I have made to code. Please let me know once you add me to repo

Comment: i am sorry i cant do that because this is a university project and my teacher is going to check that later. Is it possible to post the code somewhere else?

Comment: I can send you zip with the answer. Can you please give me any other thing where I can share with you

Comment: can u send me the zip file via email?

Answer (score 0):

In your html you need to do something like this

```
<p>{{usersFirstName}}</p>
```

In your ts code, once you get the response from the server set this usersFirstName.

```
usersFirstName : string;
getUser() {
    const userName = this.angForm2.value.searchText;
    console.log(this.angForm2.value, userName);
    this.searchservice.getElasticResult(userName).subscribe(user => (this.user = user)
this.usersFirstName = user.name;
);
  }
```

Comment: thanks for ur reply, i did that but still empty <p>